# Video.js can't take video in mp4

Tags: vue.js, video.js

I want to take a video in mp4. But with `this.player.recordedData`, I'm taking only `mkv` format and I can't change it. So I was trying to use something like:

```
console.log(this.player.record().video);
```

But it's giving the error:

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined",
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined.

Here are the options:

```js
player: '',
options: {
  controls: true,
  autoplay: false,
  fluid: false,
  loop: false,
  width: 320,
  height: 240,
  bigPlayButton: false,
  controlBar: {
    volumePanel: false
  },
  plugins: {
    record: {
      audio: true,
      video: true,
      debug: true,
      videoMimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=H264'
    },
  },
},
mounted() {
 /* eslint-disable no-console */
     this.player = videojs('#myVideo', this.options, () => {
     // print version information at startup
     var msg = 'Using video.js ' + videojs.VERSION +
     ' with videojs-record ' + videojs.getPluginVersion('record') +
     ' and recordrtc ' + RecordRTC.version;
     videojs.log(msg);
     });

     // device is ready
     this.player.on('deviceReady', () => {
        console.log('device is ready!');
     });

     // user clicked the record button and started recording
     this.player.on('startRecord', () => {
        console.log('started recording!');
     });

     // user completed recording and stream is available
     this.player.on('finishRecord', () => {
        console.log(this.player);
        var myfile = this.player.recordedData;
        const chunks = [];
        chunks.push(myfile);
        this.attachments.push({
        file: this.player.recordedData,
        uploaded: 0
        });
      });

      // error handling
      this.player.on('error', (element, error) => {
         console.warn(error);
      });

      this.player.on('deviceError', () => {
          console.error('device error:', this.player.deviceErrorCode);
      });
}
```

Comment: `this.player` is defined?

Comment: yes.
            this.player = videojs('#myVideo', this.options, () => {
                // print version information at startup
                var msg = 'Using video.js ' + videojs.VERSION +
                    ' with videojs-record ' + videojs.getPluginVersion('record') +
                    ' and recordrtc ' + RecordRTC.version;
                videojs.log(msg);
            });

I'm taking data but in wrong format idk

Comment: Can you please add the full code to the question?